# Extract text between two strings using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract text between "`description =`" and "`revision`"

```
  name = test
    description = description1
description1.1
description1.2
    revision = -
```

With the SQL currently I am using

```
DECLARE @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(64);

SET @SEARCHSTRING = ' description =';

SELECT 
SUBSTRING(ed.[mg_file_data], CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,
ed.[mg_file_data]) + LEN(@SEARCHSTRING), CHARINDEX(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ed.[mg_file_data], CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING,
ed.[mg_file_data])) - CHARINDEX(@SEARCHSTRING, ed.[mg_file_data]) - LEN(@SEARCHSTRING)) AS description
```

I am getting:

```
description1
```

But I am looking for

```
description1
description1.1
description1.2
```

> Note: mg_file_data is a property where text files are stored

Comment: Show us your current query, the one giving the description1 only result.

Comment: What is your SQL server version?

Comment: Hint: `PATINDEX()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have any repeat of 'revision'

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text, CHARINDEX('description =', @Text), CHARINDEX('revision',@text) - CHARINDEX('description =', @Text) + Len('revision'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `PATINDEX()` as the following

```
SELECT S,
       SUBSTRING(S,
       NULLIF(FPI, 0) + 15,
       NULLIF(SPI, 0) - (FPI + 15)) Result
FROM
(
  VALUES
  ('name = test description = description1 description1.1 description1.2 revision = -'),
  ('name = test description = description1  whatever you revision = - want'),
  ('Nothing here'),
  ('description=')
) T(S)
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES(PATINDEX('% description = %', S), PATINDEX('% revision = %', S))
) PIX(FPI, SPI)
```

See how it's [working online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ba5c3d59bffab092d3ecc90664198356)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can use `SPLIT_STRING` as below to get your required output:

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a08be54c6eecb049d5d9e8f88cae7020)

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(MAX) = 'name = test
description = description1
description1.1
description1.2
revision = -'


SELECT 
LTRIM(RTRIM(VALUE)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(
   SUBSTRING(
        @T,
        CHARINDEX('description =',@T,1)+13,
        LEN(@T)-
        (
            CHARINDEX('description =',@T,1)+13 +
            (
                LEN(@T) - CHARINDEX('revision',@T,1))
            )
        ), '
') 
WHERE VALUE <> ''
```

I have consider 'Enter' as a delimiter here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with STRING_SPLIT and CHARINDEX as given below:

```sql
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(8000) = 'name = test
    description = description1
description1.1
description1.2
    revision = -'

SELECT REPLACE(value,'revision','') 
from string_split(@TEST, N'=') as o
WHERE CHARINDEX('revision',value) > 0;
```

**Resultset**
`description1 description1.1 description1.2`

Answer (score 0):

I would use XML here:

```
DECLARE @T NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
N'name = test
description = description1
description1.1
description1.2
revision = -';

SELECT CAST(CONCAT('<x>',REPLACE(REPLACE(@T,'description = ','<descr>'),'revision =','</descr>'),'</x>') AS XML)
       .value('(/x/descr/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

The idea in short:

We create an XML like this

```
<x>name = test
<descr>description1
description1.1
description1.2
</descr> -</x>
```

The value you are looking for is now the `text()` node within `<descr>`. This value we get with the XML method `.value()`.